# How to call a windows batch script with wildcard filenames as command line arguments

Tags: batch-file, wildcard

I have a little windows batch script that does nothing but prints all its command line arguments (proba.bat)

```
@echo off
:loop
  if "%~1"=="" goto cont
  echo %1
  shift & goto loop
:cont
```

I expected that this script would print all .mp4 files if I call it like this:

```
proba *.mp4
```

But instead it simply prints *.mp4 literally. 
This would be so easy on linux, but here I can not get it work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: My impression is that the dos prompt (cmd.exe) can not make any wildcard expansion. It is some specific commands (such as copy, dir, move) which do this expansion themselves. Is this correct? That would be a shame.

Comment: try `dir %1` rather than `echo %1`, use `/b` to get a bare list if that's what you're after. Otherwise, look at the `for` command.

Comment: Your command line argument is a string: `*.mp4`, not a list of files.

Comment: @user3555951 Yes, you are correct.  Unless protected, Unix shells expand wildcards in a command-line _before_ passing the results to the command whereas DOS/Windows just pass parameters as entered (and commands that _want_ to expand wildcards have to do so themselves).

Answer (score 2):

This emulates what you are trying to do:

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("%~1") do echo "%%a"
```

Comment: @ssnobody  Please add your words in a comment - I have no idea what you are saying here and your link doesn't mention `%~1` at all.  The variables with a tilda in that link are entirely different.  *ssnobody* *wrote*  "According to the [For][1] command's documentation this works because within a For loop, %~1 "expands" %1 and results in something remarkably similar to traditional wildcard expansion.
 
  [1]: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx
"

Comment: You don't mention why it works. Only that it does and I explained why. If you replace the number 1 with the letter I, you can see it IS explicitly mentioned in the documention, under the section titled "variable substitution" it says "The following table lists optional syntax (for any variable I)." and specifies that "%~I" "Expands %I which removes any surrounding quotation marks ("")."

Comment: @ssnobody  So all you are saying is that the quotes are removed.  Yes, the tilda does that in `"%~1"` and the reason is to handle long filenames and paths and also to handle poison characters for batch files.  It has no other function in the `for` command as you see above.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that it does shell wildcard expansion. In linux, you can do "proba *.mp4" and the shell will expand this to echo <list of all files ending in mp4>. In Windows, the command prompt doesn't have any concept of wildcard expansion so "proba *.mp4" will send the literal string "*.mp4" as an argument rather than a list of files. However, within FOR loops, the tilde causes the wildcard expansion we would normally expect from a shell that performs expansion (e.g. bash).

Comment: The tilde prefix IS what causes wildcard expansion. It's not only me that says so, the tilde prefix to I in %~I, according to the documentation: "Expands %I".

Comment: @ssnobody - foxidrive is correct, though the idea isn't getting across.  The CMD documentation is long, convoluted and often hiding, but it is all there.  A) the `~` in `%~1` strips off any quotes from the value of `%1` B) The quotes in `"%~1"` put local quotes back on. This combination ensures you only have one set of quotes on a value. C) The `for %%a in ("%~1")` is what expands any wildcards in the value of `"%~1"`, then passes each as the value of `%%a` to the body of the for loop.